# For loop as an input parameter of a function in python

Tags: python, sudoku

I am trying to understand solving Sudoku in Python from [this](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html) website. I couldn't understand the "Search" Function in particular the application of "some" function in the "search".

```
def search(values):
"Using depth-first search and propagation, try all possible values."
if values is False:
    return False ## Failed earlier
if all(len(values[s]) == 1 for s in squares): 
    return values ## Solved!
## Chose the unfilled square s with the fewest possibilities
n,s = min((len(values[s]), s) for s in squares if len(values[s]) > 1)
return some(search(assign(values.copy(), s, d)) 
    for d in values[s])

def some(seq):
    "Return some element of seq that is true."
    for e in seq:
        if e: return e
    return False
```

`values` which is the input of the `search` is a dictionary (key: name of each square, value: string of possible values for that square). In the `search` we try to find one square( a square is a place holder of one number in Sudoku) which has the least number of possible values to fill. Then, the `assign` function is called for each of that values. the output of `assign` can be `false` or can be the new dictionary `values`. I am wondering what is the purpose of "some" function here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
search(assign(values.copy(), s, d)) 
for d in values[s]
```

is a generator expression that will recursively call `search` for each possible value that is valid for `values[s]`. It will give us a bunch of results - one for each `d in values[s]`. Each result will either be a dictionary (yay success) or `False` (boo, failure).

What `some` does is just pick the first success case in the group - otherwise return `False`.

A logically equivalent approach would be:

```
for d in values[s]:
    e = search(assign(values.copy(), s, d))
    if e: return e
return False
```